# Cocoa: saveAction called 2 times with notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have a custom class for NSButton called `MyButton` where I post a notification for a quicksave
`MyButton.m`:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(id)sender{
    [super mouseDown:sender];
    [super mouseUp:sender];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"quickSave" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

in `AppDelegate` I get the notification for the quick save:
`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Saving...");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    }
}
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveAction:) name:@"quickSave" object:nil];
}
```

Via the `NSLog "Saving..."` I see that the saveAction is called 2 times. Why?

P.S: the notification calls 2 times every function I insert in the `selector:` field, so maybe it has to do with the `-(void)awakeFromNib{...}` because I see that it's called twice (there are two different self inside the awakeFromNib).

UPDATE: I've "solved" the problem binding in Interface Builder the Application as an AppDelegate delegate and then adding the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveAction:) name:@"quickSave" object:nil];` inside the `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{...}`. I don't know if it's a real solution and obviously it is not an answer to my question (why awakeFromNib is called 2 times), but it might be useful to someone. Does anyone have a clue?

UPDATE2: the right managedobjectcontext is the one called in `awakeFromNib` the second time, the first one (identical in `awakeFromNib` and `applicationDidFinishLaunching`) is wrong.
My app is a statusbar app, the first awakeFromNib is called when i start the app and the second one when a preference window is opened.

Comment: this is the log with sender and self:
`Saving...
sender: NSConcreteNotification 0x101915b70 {name = quickSave}
self: <AppDelegate: 0x101927730>
Saving...
sender: NSConcreteNotification 0x101915b70 {name = quickSave}
self: <AppDelegate: 0x1005374c0>`

there are two different self, I've also tried to do a `removeObserver` right before the `addObserver` but it's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log message indicates that two different instances of AppDelegate receive a single notification. Probably you instantiated AppDelegate twice. Ensure you are not manually doing `[[AppDelegate alloc] init]` or something, and not putting more than one AppDelegate object in  NIB.

Comment: the second awakeFromNib is called when I open a window, however I've tried to remove any delegation but nothing change. There's no import of AppDelegate in my files.

Comment: if I'm right, the "first self" is the AppDelegate class and the "second self" is a "NSKVONotifying_AppDelegate".

Comment: ok, there was an appdelegate blue object in the statusbarmenu xib, but there was another label name on it so the horrible mistake... 2 xib calling the same appdelegate